# Close div with jQuery which opened with data toggle attribute?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, accordion

I have a few hidden divs which open using bootstrap and data toggle. I can't have multiple hidden divs shown, so when one is opened, I want the others to close.

This is the jQuery I've tried, but I'm not getting an alert when #add-alert-box is closed. I have a [demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/6PHhX/3/). Is this possible or will I have to activate each hidden div using jQuery and not the data attributes?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#add-alert-box").collapse({
        toggle: false
    })

    $('#add-alert-box').on('hide', function () {
        alert('test');
        console.log('test');
    })

});
```

Comment: the hide event will not work here since the div is not set to hidden here, rather its height is changed to 0px

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better and easier implementation. You should use Jquery ui Accordion. Check this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Bootstrap has an accordion built in with parent attributes to close all other open divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8">
                    <div class="tabs">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs top-nav pull-right" id="tabs">
                        <li class="top-nav-item" style="visibility:hidden"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-left icon-white"></i></a></li>
                        <li style="background-color:white">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="top-nav-item"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>&nbsp;HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav-item"><a href="#showroom" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-car icon-white"></i>SHOWROOM</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav-item"><a href="#cars" data-toggle="tab">CARS</a></li>
                        <li style="background-color:white">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="top-nav-item"><a href="#shortlisted" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>&nbsp;SHORTLISTED</a></li>
                        <li class="top-nav-item"><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i>&nbsp;SETTINGS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                        <div id="home" class="tab-pane">
                            Home
                        </div>
                        <div id="showroom" class="tab-pane">
                            Showroom
                        </div>
                        <div id="cars" class="tab-pane well">
                            Cars
                        </div>
                        <div id="shortlisted" class="tab-pane">
                            Shortlisted
                        </div>
                        <div id="settings" class="tab-pane">
                            Settings
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Zyxjt/1/

Comment: This is tabbed content, not really what I am looking to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

you can check the basic demo and style and color it according to your needs.

**http://jsfiddle.net/76MbN/4/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sideContent').hide();
    $('.sideHeader').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $slideContent = $(this).next()
        var slideDown =  $slideContent.is(":not(:visible)");
        $('.sideContent').slideUp('fast');

        if (slideDown)
            $slideContent.slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```